# Generating/Placing k random items in a 2d array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, random

I have a 2d array, matrix of a sort (m x n). I need to generate '1' in **k** cells, but the **probability** of it should **be equal for each cell**.

for example, if k=3, we pick **randomly** where to place the 3  '1's :

[0, 0, 0, 0]

[0, 1, 1, 0]

[1, 0, 0, 0]

At first, I tackled this by generating a Random of modulu m * n (rows * columns).
But, that means that we could theoretically get to the end of the matrix without generating a single '1'.

Then, I read about *Yates Shuffle*, but wasn't sure whether that's wise and even feasible to implement it with that.

What is an efficient way to implement this?

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: I'm using Java, but the answer can be in any mainstream language or even pseudo-code, as I want to understand the algorithm/approach itself.

Comment: You can generate a list like this: `{ (0,0), (0,1), ..., (0,n-1), (1,0), (1,1), ..., (1,n-1), ..., (m-1,n-1) }`, that represents all the possible indices of the matrix. Then, use a random number between 0 and the length of the array to choose an element, then remove this element from the array and repeat with the new length.

Comment: will the probability really be equal to all? for first iteration of k, the probability would be 1/(m*n) , then the next iteration would be 1/(m*n-1), and so on. Or I am missing here something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is essentially a problem of "sampling without replacement": Out of *mn* cells, choose *k* of them without replacement. There are many approaches to this problem, depending on how big *mn* is in relation to *k*. If *mn* is relatively small, then a Fisher–Yates shuffle will work well; make a list of cells, shuffle them, then take the first *k* cells to set to 1.

For more details, see my sections on [sampling without replacement](https://peteroupc.github.io/randomfunc.html#Sampling_Without_Replacement_Choosing_Several_Unique_Items) and [shuffling](https://peteroupc.github.io/randomfunc.html#Shuffling). (Part of my comment moved here:) Different sampling algorithms have different tradeoffs in terms of time and space. For example, a Fisher–Yates shuffle has time and space complexity of O(mn), while a partial shuffle can have time complexity O(k).

Comment: so our Space complexity would be O(m * n) to store a copy of that list of cells for the Yates shuffle to apply on. and Time complexity would be O(m+n) for the Yates algorithm, to determine the k indexes? Is there a way to decrease our space complexity without affecting time complexity?

Comment: I see, that's very interesting and insightful, thanks for the help and the links! Just a question about the part where we pick the first k cells - doesn't that affect our requirement of 'equal probability'? I mean, even though the list is shuffled with equal probability thanks for Fisher-Yates, we do pick the first k cells, instead of random k indexes. no?

Comment: Take a list of _mn_ elements, and let k = 1.  Then if we choose a random item from the list, swap it with the first item, and take the first element (first _k_ elements), then the item taken will be the item randomly chosen, and the rest of the list is unshuffled.  Now let k = 2.  We choose a random item, swap it with the first, then choose another random item (other than the first) and swap it with the second, and if we take the first _k_ = 2 items, the items taken will be the items randomly chosen, and the rest of the list is unshuffled.  And so on.

Comment: I see now.. 
Regarding your edit about the complexity, I've gone through the link you had posted, it seems Reservoir Sampling can be made with a space complexity of O(k), while still preserving O(m * n) for time complexity. May I ask why would you choose one over the other, and specifically in this post's case, would you go with Fisher-Yates over Reservoir?

Comment: In your case, the cells can be algorithmically determined from the index, so even though the number of items is known, reservoir sampling can be viable if space is at a premium and the time complexity of O(mn) is acceptable.