# How to randomly change some members of a 2D-matrix to zero in python?

Tags: python, algorithm, random

I have a 2D-matrix of some numbers and I want to randomly change a fraction of the non-zero members (e.x. 0.2) to become zero and then again randomly choose equal to that fraction amount (0.2) between all zeroes and give them random numbers. Is there any straight forward way to do that?
for example:
The original matrix is : x = [[1,2,3],[4,0,7],[2,10,0]]
After first step (2 randomly selected numbers change to zero): x = [[1,0,0],[4,0,7],[2,10,0]]
After second step (2 randomly selected zeros change to random numbers): x = [[1,0,5],[4,7,7],[2,10,0]]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generating/Placing k random items in a 2d array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61065565/generating-placing-k-random-items-in-a-2d-array)

Comment: Not exactly. I want to know a straight forward codes with pandas or numpy. I know the algorithm and I have written some codes but it takes a lot of time.

Comment: The main problem is to randomly select some elements in a matrix and make them zero. I know how this can be done in 1D arrays with numpy.random.choice(). but it doesn't work for 2D arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method:

```
arr = np.ones((5, 5)) # Your matrix
print("Before Replacement")
print(arr)

# Number of elements to replace
num_replaced = 3 

# Random (x, y) coordinates
indices_x = np.random.randint(0, arr.shape[0], num_replaced)
indices_y = np.random.randint(0, arr.shape[1], num_replaced)

arr[indices_x, indices_y] = 0
print("After replacement")
print(arr)
```

Sample Output:

> Before Replacement
>
> [[1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
>
> [1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
>
> [1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
>
> [1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
>
> [1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]]
>
> After replacement
>
> [[0. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
>
> [1. 0. 1. 1. 1.]
>
> [1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
>
> [1. 0. 1. 1. 1.]
>
> [1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]]

EDIT

---

You can use `np.random.choice` instead on `np.random.randint` as follows:

```
indices_x = np.random.choice(range(arr.shape[0]), num_replaced, replace=REPLACE)
indices_y = np.random.choice(range(arr.shape[1]), num_replaced, replace=REPLACE)
```

Here, you can easily switch between sampling with or without replacement.

Comment: Since sampling is with replacement, the probability of that happening is very low. But it is statistically possible.

Comment: You can replace `np.random.randint(0, arr.shape[0], num_replaced)` with `np.random.choice(range(arr.shape[0]), num_replaced, replace=False)` for both axes to change this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to create a simple function for this. So you can input the number desired.

```
import pandas as pd
import random

def random_converter(dataframe, k, isZero=True, input_data='random_value'):
  # Copy df
  dataframe_local = dataframe.copy()

  if input_data=='random_value':
    input_data = random.randint(0,10)

  ki = 0
  while ki < k:
    row_selected = dataframe_local.sample(1).T

    # VERIFY CONDITION
    if isZero:
      attributes = row_selected[row_selected.iloc[:, 0] == 0]
    else:
      attributes = row_selected[row_selected.iloc[:, 0] != 0]

    # No zero in the row
    if attributes.size == 0:
      continue

    column_index = attributes.index
    row_index = attributes.columns
    dataframe_local.iloc[row_index, column_index] = input_data    

    ki += 0
  return dataframe_local
```